# Setting Background with setBackgroungDrawable function in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, background-image, blurry, setbackground

Okey I have a problem with setting a picture for the background. At first I just set the background from 'properities' box. I copy the .jpg file to my drawable folder and just click on the *background* properity from *properities* box then select the file from the resources folder. That was okey and it worked but then i wanted to make the background blurry and I found a class that is wrote for that, called *BlurBuilder* and I put that class to my project. Everything is okey to this point, I added the class but when I tried to apply the funciton from that class as shown in an example like that:

```
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(MainActivity.this,myBackgroundFile);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), blurredBitmap ) );
```

editor says *'cannot resolve symbol 'view' '*.
I tryied to change the second line as;

```
View.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), blurredBitmap ) );
```

But this time android studio says *'Non-static method 'setBackgroudDrawable(android.graphic.drawables.Drawable) cannot be referenced from a static context*

Here's the BlurBuilder class I used:

```
public class BlurBuilder {
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDİT: I want to make my activity's background a blurry image.

Comment: I assume view is your ImageView variable name?

Comment: No it's not. I just started android programming. So I just leave there as I copied from example. I know I should change it but I don't know what to do exactly. How should change it? And I'm trying set the picture for the whole layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a non-static function i.e setDrawableBackground from a non-static context which means to say that you need to create an instance of some View for example:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);    
Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(MainActivity.this,myBackgroundFile);
view.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), blurredBitmap ) );
```

Once done now you can call any function that `view` supports.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I'm trying to set the picture as background to my whole layout not for an ImageView. What should I do.

Comment: does the layout fill the entire screen?

Comment: You don't need a View per say, you can call the same setBackgroundDrawable on a Layout!

Comment: So just don't use an View just get your layout from xml resource or if you did it in code call the same method and set it as contentView().  Everything should work

Comment: Okey, I think I misspoke. I want to make the background of my activity a blurry image.

Comment: so call this in onCreate():                                                                                                    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_image);

Comment: Glad to help                                                                     ------------

Answer (score 1):

Got it,

Add the following in XML (main_activity.xml or whatever is your file):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/whole_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android" />
```

Add the following in there [in Main Activity] : this will force scale the image to display screen size and use the whole display to show the image.

```
    /* where you set the activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.your_main_activity);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    /* adapt the image to the size of the display */
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(MainActivity.this,myBackgroundFile);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(blurredBitmap,size.x,size.y,true);

    /* fill the background ImageView with the resized image */
    ImageView iv_background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whole_background);
    iv_background.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that but wouldn't that ImageView just made every other elements on my layout disappear.

Comment: Not exactl. :) If you are using AppCompactActivity and using FloatingActionButton then it won't. As I am not sure of your use case, you can simply have a blurred image and set the image in layout background so rest view remains same.